# Regex is not matching in the way that I want to

Tags: python, regex

Hi I'm new to regexes.

I have a string that I want to match any number of A-Z a-z 0-9 - and _

I've tried the following in python however it always matches, even the empty space. Can someone tell me why that is?

```
re.match(r'[A-Za-z0-9_-]+', 'gfds9 41.-=,434')
```

Comment: Works fine for me too (Python 2.7.1).

Comment: Assuming it should match "gfds9", works fine on Python 2.7.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex matches one or more of those characters. Your text starts with one or more of those characters, hence it matches. If you want it to *only* match those characters then you have to match them from the beginning to the end of the text.

```
re.match(r'^[A-Za-z0-9_-]+$', 'gfds9 41.-=,434')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the alternative for it maybe it will work for you:

```
[\w-]+
```

EDIT:

Although the initial regex you provided also works for me.